# Use VBA loops to search for a changing list of values and delete them?

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I've been working on an excel sheet where I am using a macro to basically run a 'Find Function' to find a word/phrase on a separate sheet and then delete the entire column that this word/phrase is located in. Currently, thanks to my last post ([Is there a way to use the find function with changing, user inputted values in an excel macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790210/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-find-function-with-changing-user-inputted-values-in-a/17790725?noredirect=1#comment25959668_17790725)) I have this:

```
Dim strFind As String
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim i As Integer


strFind = Sheets("Instructions").Range("E56").Value
Set rngFind = Sheets("Forecast").Cells.Find(What:=strFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
check if value is found
Do While Not rngFind Is Nothing
If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
   i = 0
        Do While rngFind.Offset(0, i + 1) = ""
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    rngFind.Resize(1, i + 1).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
Loop
End If
```

This works perfectly to reference Cell C53 (which is where the word/phrase is inputted by a user) and then go to the 'Forecast' sheet and delete the columns the word/phrase is located in along with the subsequent columns to the right until the next populated column. However, I need it to do 2 more things.

- Currently it only finds the word once, even though it may exist in the sheet multiple times, and I need it to delete all of them- basically it "finds next" instead of "find all". I was thinking making a loop so that once it finds one and deletes the column, it finds the same word again and deletes that column (and the subsequent empty rows next to it) until the word is no longer on the sheet at all.
- Secondly, I need it to find more than one word/phrase. Right now it references cell 'C53' but I need it to then go on to 'C54' and do the same thing, then 'C55', then 'C56', etc. etc. UNTIL it reaches a cell that simply has a '0' in it. The problem is, the list size in column C is always different (but always starts at C53). The Once it reaches a "0" (not a blank cell), I need it to stop.

Any help with this 'Loop Inception' problem would be greatly appreciated! I am very new to VBA and I was just given the task of doing this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a good foundation here.

> Any help with this 'Loop Inception' problem would be greatly appreciated!

I think something like this should help with your first point (untested, but this is the idea of using another `Do` loop, until `rngFind Is Nothing`):

```
Set rngFind = Sheets("Forecast").Cells.Find(What:=strFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
Do While Not rngFind Is Nothing '## Makes sure the value is found before operating the rest of the loop
    i = 0
        Do While rngFind.Offset(0, i + 1) = ""
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    rngFind.Resize(1, i + 1).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
    '## Find the NEXT instanct of strFind within rngFind
    Set rngFind = Sheets("Forecast").Cells.FindNext(What:=strFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
Loop
```

For your second point, store a list of values to search for in an array.  You can use the Split function on a comma-delimited string to create an array. Useful for smaller lists. Otherwise you might need to use a different method to create the array.

## Updated Per Comments:

```
Dim valsToSearch() As Variant
Dim val As Variant
Dim numberOfValues as Long

numberOfValues = CInt(Application.InputBox("How Many Search Terms?"))
valsToSearch = Range("C53").Resize(numberOfValues,1)
```

Then, enclose above in a `For/Next` loop to iterate over the values in the array:

```
For each val in valsToSearch
    strFind = val
    Set rngFind = Sheets("Forecast").Cells.Find(What:=strFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
    Do While Not rngFind Is Nothing '## Makes sure the value is found before operating the rest of the loop
        i = 0
            Do While rngFind.Offset(0, i + 1) = ""
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        rngFind.Resize(1, i + 1).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
        '## Find the NEXT instanct of strFind within rngFind
        Set rngFind = Sheets("Forecast").Cells.FindNext(What:=strFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
    Loop 
Next
```

Comment: Great, I got the first part to work! But for the second part, the "values" of text being searched for are always changing. Also, sometimes I will have 100 values to search for (hence going from C53:C153), but other times I'll only have 25 values, etc. However, there will always be a zero in the row following the end of the "values" being searched for. Any ideas to loop until it reaches 0?

Comment: Yes we can store those values in the array directly, instead of using the `Split` function on a delimited string. I will update my answer momentarily.

Comment: Hmm that's a different way to do it. The problem is this is going to be used as a type of user-input sheet. They choose from a dropdown list, and this list automatically populates the values in column (C) that I am searching for with the Macro. So I don't really want to have to have each person count the rows and put that in the input box. Does that make more sense? Sorry this is really confusing trying to explain it all haha

Comment: @JoeGay there are several ways this could be accomplished. There are literally thousands of threads on this forum about "how to find the last row in a column/worksheet/etc." Please review some of those.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that solving the first part of this made the whole thing a heck of a lot easier. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

> I've been working on an excel sheet where I am using a macro to
>   basically run a 'Find Function' to find a word/phrase on a separate
>   sheet and then delete the entire column that this word/phrase is
>   located in.

If I understand you correctly - it seems to me you are over-complicating your sub:

```
Sub DeleteColumnsWithString()

Dim strFind As String
Dim rngFind As Range

strFind = Sheets("Instructions").Range("C53").Value

Do
    Set rngFind = Sheets("Forecast").Cells.Find(What:=strFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        rngFind.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Loop Until rngFind Is Nothing

End Sub
```

If you wanted to do multiple strings you could do it like this:

```
Sub DeleteColumnsWithAnyOfTheseStrings()

Dim strFind As String
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim SearchTerms As Range

Set SearchTerms = Sheets("Instructions").Range("C53:C55")

For Each Cell In SearchTerms.Cells
    strFind = Cell.Value

    Do
        Set rngFind = Sheets("Forecast").Cells.Find(What:=strFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            rngFind.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Loop Until rngFind Is Nothing
Next Cell

End Sub
```

**UPDATED PER YOUR COMMENTS:**

```
Sub DeleteColumnsWithTheseStringsAndToTheRightBlanksColumns()

Dim strFind As String
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim strFindAddress As String
Dim SearchTerms As Range
Dim Counter As Long

Set SearchTerms = Sheets("Instructions").Range("C53:C55")

For Each Cell In SearchTerms.Cells
    Counter = 0
    strFind = Cell.Value

    Do
        Set rngFind = Sheets("Forecast").Cells.Find(What:=strFind, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            strFindAddress = rngFind.Address
            Do
                Range(strFindAddress).EntireColumn.Delete
                Counter = Counter + 1
            Loop Until Range(strFindAddress).Value <> "" Or Counter >= 100
        End If
    Loop Until rngFind Is Nothing
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I don't think I worded my question the way I should of haha. The reason my code is complicated like that is so that it finds the column the word is in and deletes it, but also deletes the columns to the right of that one (in row 1), until the next populated cell. It's a little confusing to explain. For the second part, I like the range idea but the range I'm dealing with is always changing (sometimes it will be 100 rows, sometimes only 70, etc. etc.) any ideas?